# See complete tooltip error message for Data Flow SSIS element in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis, dataflow-diagram

One of the elements in my SSIS data flow diagram shows an error in the tooltip when I hover the cursor over it.

[image]

**Where** can I see the **full text** of this **error message**?

The element that displays this tooltip is the one labeled "Specs".
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The message will show in full form in the Error List window.  Turn it on via View | Error List, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.
Make sure that `Warnings` is selected as shown here:

[image]

Comment: I have 72 warnings, mostly truncation and no error output columns at row redirecting on errors. Now I want to clear the errors one by one, but finding 1 out of the 72 warnings is looking for a needle in a haystack. Any idea?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question - do you mean you have a lot of warnings and few errors, and can't easily find the errors? In that case, just hit the "Warnings" button to turn their display off.

Comment: I mean, if there are a few warnings it's easy to find it. But I have over 70 warnings. In order to be able to read the whole warning pop-up message, I need to find the warning back in the `Error list`, which is a lot more time consuming if you have a big list of warning already

Comment: @IvanM, while I realise that this is probably too late to help you, the answer to your question is to just fix each problem one by one... you should find that fixing one problem can actually clear more than one error.

Comment: It's additionally confusing that a message can appear on a Data Flow item with the "warning" yellow triangle icon shown, even though messages in the Error List are signified with the blue "i" icon. This confused the heck out of me when I instinctively went to the Error List to see the full message, but was expecting a Warning, not a Message.