# SSIS/SSDT Warnings Don't Appear in Error List

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

Essentially, I encounter the same problem as the question below, except that the accepted answer does not resolve it. I have neither warnings nor errors in the Error List:

[See complete tooltip error message for Data Flow SSIS element in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743417/see-complete-tooltip-error-message-for-data-flow-ssis-element-in-visual-studio)

Similar to the question noted above I can see a truncated warning message on the Data Flow design surface.

[image]

However, no corresponding warning is visible in Visual Studio's Error List view.

[image]

How can I view the entire warning?

Comment: In VS 2019, I can edit the item and press __OK__, and they suddenly show up. Saving then makes them disappear. Make sure the Error List is set to "Entire Solution."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit misleading from Visual Studio and could have been handled better. The long and the short of it is that the Error List window lists only messages that are related to build issues.

The warnings and errors that you see in design time are related to the execution flow. In other words, a package can be built correctly but is designed in such a way that it will generate an error. For more reading:

[MSDN: Cannot see errors or warnings in SSIS - why ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fcd537ad-7610-4c17-9ea5-2b9c461224c3/cannot-see-errors-or-warnings-in-ssis-why-?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

[SQLServerCentral: Cannot see errors or warnings in SSIS – why ?](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/cannot-see-errors-or-warnings-in-ssis-why)

You will need to run the package in debug mode and then go to the `Progress` window. From there, you can see all messages (e.g., information, warnings, errors, etc.). Some messages may be so long that they cannot be seen. For those messages, you can click on them and paste them into your favorite text editor.

[image]

Note: when you stop debugging, the `Progress` window changes its name to `Execution Results` and the error List window becomes available.

[image]

**Update**

Per Hadi's follow-up comment, I was initially able to re-create the OPs problem by just modifying an existing package to create the warning message. I then built and ran the project with without receiving any error messages.

Now, after having left the office and shutting down Visual Studio, I am unable to recreate the error. The Error List window now populates with the messages. I tried building a new package from scratch without any luck either. My best recommendation at this point would be to, as with all Microsoft products, restart the application if it is not working as it should be.

Comment: i am using Visual Studio 2015 and the warnings are shown in the Error List before executing the package. (same IsSorted warning) they will disappear only when i build the solution. If i double click on the components again it is shown in the error list

Comment: @Hadi Confirmed, I was able to build and then open the Error List window and see the full warning message. Even after I ran the package, the Error List window was populated. This is weird because that was not the result I was getting yesterday, per my screenshots above. The only difference is that I have restarted Visual Studio. Though, I could be missing something considering I haven't yet had my second cup of coffee today. Thank you for the assist. :)

Comment: since the OP decided to accept the answer, then i must agree with it. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

This text truncation issue/bug is not just tooltips.
It's in SSIS Toolbox (description box at bottom) - no way to see the entire text describing the task/component (if not too big you can increase the width of the pane but that is not really acceptable).

(VS/SSDT 2019)

Answer (score 0):

### Many things to try

1. Try to change the combobox selected value from `Build + Intellisense` to `Build only`
2. Open and close the OLEDB Source by double clicking on it, since you tried to build the package the warnings disappears from the Error List, you must revalidate the component to show them
3. Try to update the Visual Studio 2017 to the latest release

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried 1 and 2 to no effect. My VS 2017 is already up to date.